# I need the javascript checkboxes.click(function()) to start when the page first loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, pageload

I am using the following js code to disable the form submit button until at least one checkbox selection is checked.

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

checkboxes.click(function() {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

The problem is the code doesn't work when the page first loads. When the user first comes to the page, he is able to click submit but if he checks something and then unchecks everything the submit is then disabled.

It looks like I need the code to start when the page first loads. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why dont you add 'disabled' attribute to your button html

Comment: that code wont disable anything, it's adding a click HANDLER to the check boxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));` to disable the the submit button at first. Also, better wrap it in either domready or onload to ensure jQuery can access the fully rendered `DOM`.

```js
$(function() {
  var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
          submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

  checkboxes.click(function() {
      submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
  });
  
  // Add this line to set init status of the submit.
  // submitButt.attr("disabled", true)); is ok as you don't have any checked checkbox when page loaded.
  submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="c1"/ >c1
<input type="checkbox" id="c2"/ >c2
<input type="checkbox" id="c3"/ >c3
<input type="submit" value="click" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery use its `ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

    checkboxes.click(function() {
        submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
    });
});
```

That way code gets only executed when the page is loaded and jQuery is ready. So click handlers can be set upon checkboxes that actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

2 options: 1) add in your html code the attribute "disabled"; 2) Use this code

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
        submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

    checkboxes.click(function() {
        submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
window.onload = function () {
      submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
}
```

... and externalize the content into a function which is called for onload and for checkboxes.click.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function and call it on page load and on click of checkbook.

Note : you can change function name.

Please check below code snippet :

```js
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
var submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

var onloadCheckboxesCheck = function() {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
}

onloadCheckboxesCheck();

checkboxes.click(function() {
   onloadCheckboxesCheck();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="lname">
    <input type="checkbox" name="lname">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lname">
            <input type="checkbox" name="lname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to trigger event:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(e) {
    $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', 0 === $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length);
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="submit" />
```

- `.trigger('change')` will fire change event on the checkbox.
- `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')` will give you list of `checked`, check-boxes